# java program is compiling but not running in Blue J

Tags: bluej

JAVA program is compiling but not running in Blue J

The program was about string manipulation.I tried to run the program but it didnt show result as it didnt run after compiling. It didnt show any error still program is not running.

Comment: Can you please provide the code? It's impossible to answer your question without any sources